# Global.asax routes erroring 404 because of path

Tags: javascript, c#, global-asax

I am getting an invalid path from

```
Router.Get("API/Customers", "IndexAction", *TypeOf(APIController))
```

I am getting the path:  http://website/api/customers

I should be getting :  http://website/rootfolder/api/customers

It works on the local desktop but not on the server.

Comment: Anybody know how to fix the path.  Help.

Comment: Please give us a bit more context and post the whole method, from where this code is called

Comment: It is inside the global.asax handler.

Comment: Again: please post the whole method

Comment: got it.  I just had to eliminate the .. from the path and it worked.